# How to push a docker image that has a tag different from docker hub repository?

Tags: docker

Let's say I have an account on docker hub and my username is `hub_user`.

I create a repository called `react-dev` on it.

Now on my machine, I have created an image tagged `company/react/dev`.

I can see it using `docker image ls`:

```
REPOSITORY                        TAG           IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
company/react/dev                  latest        f344922a299e   7 minutes ago   368MB
```

Now I'm stuck at pushig this image into that hub repository.

This command does not work:

`docker push company/react/dev`

> Using default tag: latest
> The push refers to repository [docker.io/company/react/dev]
> f63cd7f19f75: Preparing
> e8aee5ec6588: Preparing
> 48ee8f528027: Preparing
> f3abd083ca1f: Preparing
> d02e39b7f91a: Preparing
> 0586d9cce1ac: Waiting
> 48286fbe1b87: Waiting
> f22adfb1c0f3: Waiting
> 9a5d14f9f550: Waiting
> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `hub_user/react-dev` when push.

For your scenario, you could use `docker tag` to create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/).

Then, something like next could work:

```
$ docker tag company/react/dev hub_user/react-dev
$ docker push hub_user/react-dev
```

Comment: You mean the name of the image and the name of the repository should be the same?

Comment: YES, at least, this is how I usually did, you could try if this works.

Comment: That's a very stupid design from docker team. Yeah it worked. But it ruined our naming and structure and design. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well the tag and push should follow the convention like this while pushing to dockerhub.

```
dockerhub_username/repo_name:$TAG
```

so when building/tagging image it should be like this

```
docker build -t hub_user/react-dev:latest
```

Then push the same image

```
docker push hub_user/react-dev:latest
```